# How to check if URL has http:// or https://?

Tags: magento-1.9, url, ssl

In my Magento website I have configured SSL certificate in some pages only. So how to check if the current page has `http://` or `https://`?

I am using Magento 1.9

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use below as another solution:

```
if (Mage::app()->getStore()->isFrontUrlSecure() 
    && Mage::app()->getRequest()->isSecure()
) {
    // current page is https
}else {
    // current page is http
}
```

Comment: i have added SSL in my site & i want to redirect selected page on http url instead of https. so how can i do that ?

Answer (score 10):

You can use

```
$isSecure = Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure();
```

or

```
$isSecure = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->isSecure();
```

Source [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457987/can-i-check-for-https-in-magento-phtml-files).